Changing the "main" in package.json for one specific (expo) script
I have a simple react-native library and I am trying to make it so that I can easily test the code locally.
I am using expo for local tests, and the input file for testing with expo is index.js.
However the input file for the people who download the library to use it is dist/index.js.
Is there a way to change the main file when running npm run dev?
"scripts": {
    "dev": "expo start",
}

Maybe something like expo start -main "dist/index.js" would be the most ideal.
